# How to compute deposits from the output of listsinceblock?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, listtransactions

I am writing a program that, given the JSON outputs from multiple separate RPC calls to `listsinceblock`, stores valid deposit transactions in a database and then computes the total deposit for every unique address.

From my reading the documentation, I am hoping to confirm if the following are true:

- Every transaction is unique on a combination of `txid` and `vout`.
- Every deposit will have its `category` be either `receive` or `generate`.

Further, I would like to ask:

- Should transactions of `category` of `orphan` and `immature` also be counted as deposits?
- Is a transaction that has `walletconflicts` as a non-empty array considered valid?
- Are there any other considerations that I have not taken into account if I am trying to compute total deposits for every address that occurs in the `listsinceblock` transaction list?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! This is an interesting topic. Did you find the solution to yout question?